# Why this is not working? ploting split outputs with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6

just want to ask why this code is not working, i am reading a file with 4 columns and the idea is to plot the last 3 against the 1 one. but there is an imcopatible thing that i do not get, do you have any idea how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np

import cmath as math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataplanck1 = 'COM_PowerSpect_CMB-TT-full_R3.01.txt'
dataplanck2 = 'COM_PowerSpect_CMB-EE-full_R3.01.txt'
dataplanck3 = 'COM_PowerSpect_CMB-TE-full_R3.01.txt'
datawmap1 = 'wmap_tt_spectrum_9yr_v5.txt'
datawmap2 = 'wmap_ee_spectrum_9yr_v5.txt'
datawmap3 = 'wmap_te_spectrum_9yr_v5.txt'

multipole = []
dls = []
dlse1 = []
dlse2 = []

with open(dataplanck1) as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        row = line.split()
        multipole.append(row[0])
        dls.append(row[1])
        dlse1.append(row[2])
        dlse2.append(row[3])


plt.plot(multipole, dls, label='Synthetic masked ')
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[weirdplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tcUs.png)

That makes no sense. also the data has this format:

```
 2.00000000e+00   2.25895000e+02   1.32369000e+02   5.33062000e+02
  3.00000000e+00   9.36920000e+02   4.50471000e+02   1.21230800e+03
  4.00000000e+00   6.92238000e+02   2.94111000e+02   6.66469000e+02
  5.00000000e+00   1.50170500e+03   5.74432000e+02   1.15580400e+03
  6.00000000e+00   5.57611000e+02   2.01242000e+02   3.75763000e+02
  7.00000000e+00   1.15264300e+03   3.81584000e+02   6.70824000e+02
  8.00000000e+00   6.15846000e+02   1.91997000e+02   3.23446000e+02
  9.00000000e+00   6.97821000e+02   2.14638000e+02   3.49581000e+02
  1.00000000e+01   8.03658000e+02   2.32846000e+02   3.67945000e+02
  1.10000000e+01   8.69580000e+02   2.40260000e+02   3.71043000e+02
  1.20000000e+01   7.64074000e+02   2.04951000e+02   3.10576000e+02
  1.30000000e+01   5.99003000e+02   1.58593000e+02   2.35581000e+02
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your code be `for line in fobj.readlines():`?

Comment: No, i tried with that and it did not work, what i do not get is  the plotting part, because i can save everything inside each arrays but i am not able to plot anything

Comment: What you mean in your plot statement is `plt.plot([...])`. You're currently calling `plt` which is a module.

Comment: I tried importing like import matplotlib as plt and is still not working

Answer (score 2):

`plt` is a `module`, so you cannot call it as a function

When you want to draw a plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`, you should call the function `plot`, then use `show` function to see the plot

in this case, the following lines will draw a scatterplot for you :

```
plt.plot(multipole, dls,'.')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the same:
' ' ' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_gen.py", line 52, in <module>
    plot(multipole, dls, label='Synthetic masked ')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ' ' '

Comment: you should write `plt.plot(multipole, dls, label='Synthetic masked ')` not `plot(multipole, dls, label='Synthetic masked ')` ! ok? you don't write `plt.` at first

Comment: I tried this:
plt.plot(multipole, dls, label='Synthetic masked ')
plt.show()  but i am still getting the same error even having imported the libraries as: import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_gen.py", line 52, in <module>
    plt.plot(multipole, dls, label='Synthetic masked ')
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined

Comment: you should write `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the first of your file

Comment: apparently ir worked but i am getting a weird plot, something very noisy and should be regular, isn't any incompatibility with the type of the array that split is generating?

Comment: alright, ask it in another question, upload your plot, mention me

Comment: tell us what's in your file, is that a number of integers, floats or sth else, also what kind of plot do you want to draw? pairplot, line chart, ... ?

Comment: basically float numbers in each column

Comment: ask another question, show us 2 rows of your file and also upload a figure of your plot

Comment: ok, rewrite your plot function as this one :

`plt.plot(multipole, dls, 'r.')`

Comment: check out my answer again